# Volume of a curved cone

Tags: volume

Apparently, the volume of this cone is (1/16)π(r^2)h. My question is why this is the case, can someone please geometrically explain the reason behind the 1/16 bit. The radius is supposed to be proportional to the square of its height. Thanks.
[image]

Comment: this has nothing to do with physics.

Comment: What shape would $\pi r^2h$ be the volume of?

Comment: @lemon 1/3(pi)hr^2 is the volume of a regular cone. But i cant find anything on curved cones.

Comment: That's not what I asked...

Comment: @lemon 3 cones?

Comment: A cylinder of radius $r$ and length $h$. So the geometrical rationale behind the (1/16) is you can fit 16 of them inside a cylinder. Now, why 1/16 and not some other number? Well it depends entirely on the sort of curvature - whether it's parabolic, cubic, etc... There's nothing significant about it.

Comment: @lemon you're right, but what about in a general case. Isn't there a general equation to solve the volume of these types of cones like regular cones?

Comment: @Joe yes, the general equation is called *Calculus*.

Comment: As pointed out by lemon, you need to know the functional form of the curved side in order to be able to use your calculus knowledge in calculating the volume due to revolution of a curve around some axis.

Comment: @Benjamin thanks, i understood it now. i forgot about the equation for volume of revolution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{equation} 
r=a \cdot h^2
\tag{01}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}   
dV=\pi r^{2} dh = \pi a^{2}h^{4}dh
\tag{02}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}  
V=\int_{h=0}^{h=H}\pi a^{2}h^{4}dh=\dfrac{\pi a^{2}H^{5}}{5}=\dfrac{\pi R^{2}H}{5}
\tag{03}
\end{equation}
If instead of eq.(01) your curve was
\begin{equation} 
r=a \cdot \sqrt{h^{15}}
\tag{04}
\end{equation}
then you would have 16 in the denominator.